# Changed cookie domain, but old cookie is still used

Tags: php, session-cookies

**EDITED, look at the end**

I got a Symfony 1.2 project, that was running on two domains (different app used on each domain) : www.mywebsite.com and abonnement.mywebsite.com

I had two different cookie name/domain in each app.

We decided to use the same cookie for both apps. So, i edited the config for both apps and set the cookie_domain to .mywebsite.com, and setted the cookie_name to mywebsite_cookie in boths apps.

The problem is that when I visit abonnement.mywebsite.com, the old cookie is used. Manually deleting this cookie in my browser fixes the problem, but there are thousands of users on this website and I'm wondering if there's a solution to manually delete this cookie.

I tried :

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['abonnement_cookie'])) {
    ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'abonnement.mywebsite.com);
    setcookie('abonnement_cookie', '', time() - 3600, '/');
    $this->redirect('@internet_etape_1');
}
```

But no success.

Is there a way to do it?

I'm using Firefox 9.0.1

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I found the problem, cookie was created with "host" and not "domain".

To use the current host, you need to specify '' as domain :

```
setcookie('abonnement_cookie', 0, time() - 3600, '/', '');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the domain and path that which was used to create the cookie when destroying the cookie. This is because as you have discovered, it is possible to have a cookie with the same name and different scopes for the same domain. When destroying the cookie, you must match the scope that was used to create it, so the client knows which one to destroy.

Try:

```
setcookie('abonnement_cookie', '', time() - 3600, '/', 'abonnement.mywebsite.com');
```

Comment: Doesn't work either, but after setting the cookie, I redirect to the same page so the page reloads without this cookie (cookie deleted). Unfortunately, the cookie still exists.

Comment: Just so you understand well when I'm trying to do, the cookie_domain is now set to .mywebsite.com, but the cookie I'm trying to delete is on abonnement.mywebsite.com . I'm trying to delete this cookie when accessing the abonnement.mywebsite.com URL, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I found the problem, cookie was created with "host" and not "domain".

To use the current host, you need to specify '' as domain :

    setcookie('abonnement_cookie', 0, time() - 3600, '/', '');

Hope this helps!